# Java remote debug "Read timed out" problem

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

While attempting to remote debug a Java application using eclipse, I get the following message.

```
Failed to connect to remote VM
Read timed out
```

In eclipse the debugger timeout is set to 300000ms and launch timeout to 200000ms. The remote server uses:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.282.08.1 (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.282.08.1 (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

And eclipse uses:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.265.01.1 (build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.265.01.1 (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

The remote application is started with these options

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=10004,server=y,suspend=n
```

I get connection refused without these settings, which indicates the firewall settings are correct as well. Any help in resolving this problem is appreciated.

**update**

Eclipse error log has this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:200)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.readHandshake(SocketTransportService.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$3.run(SocketTransportService.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```